# Automatic indentation of arguments list on multiple lines in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-formatting

When the list of arguments to a method grows to the point where they do not fit comfortably on one line, I like to format code such that each argument is on a separate line (following the [StyleCop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StyleCop) suggestion), like this:

```
public void MyMethod(
   int someArgument,
   double someOtherArgument,
   int someMoreArguments)
```

The problem I run into is that this formatting is "fragile" and does not get automatically reformatted when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. For instance, if I happen to insert some spaces in front of one of the arguments, it doesn't get removed, and I end up doing some tedious manual reformatting.

If I copy a method (say, to provide an overloaded signature), the argument indentation in the copy gets totally messy.
I have a similar issue with [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) statements, which I also like to format on multiple lines, like:

```
myEnumerable.
   .Where(this and that)
   .Where(this and that)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

I realize this is complete obsessive-compulsive formatting, and a very minor issue, but is there a way to make Visual Studio 2010 automatically reindent multi-line arguments following that pattern when it gets misaligned?

Answer (score 7):

For anyone searching this problem for later versions, in [Visual Studio 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2017) I found an option to do this (I am not sure if it is available in other versions).

Under menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Text editor* → *C/C++* → *Formatting* → *Indentation* → *"Within parentheses, align new lines when I type them"*.

Choose the option *"Align contents to opening parentheses"*.

Visual studio 2019 update.

Mostly the same answer but Formatting seems to have moved under Code style:
So:
Under menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Text editor* → *C/C++* → *Code Style* → *Formatting* → *Indentation* → *"Within parentheses, align new lines when I type them"*.

Choose the option *"Align contents to opening parentheses"*.

[image: Align contents]

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at [ReSharper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#ReSharper_Ultimate) from [JetBrains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains).  It has all sorts of rules that can be applied to formatting code that is much better that the built-in Visual Studio stuff.

This particular option is located at:

ReSharper → menu *Options* → *C#* → *Formatting Style* → *Line Breaks and Wrapping* → *Wrap long lines*.

I don't know if it does exactly what you want, but it does wrap long lines.

Comment: I am actually using ReSharper already; I'll check if it has an option for that.