# Visual Studio indentation of function arguments

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

[Visual Studio 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2010) indents the following C++ code as:

```
 if (Foo(arg1,
     arg2))
 {
 }
```

Is there a way to change Visual Studio formatting rules to indent the code as below:

```
 if (Foo(arg1,
         arg2))
 {
 }
```

Comment: In VS2008 which I am using: when I press 'enter' after the ',' then the new line starts at arg2?

Comment: @PoweRoy I'm using VS2010 and on enter it behaves as I described :(

Comment: @PoweRoy: I think the issue here is that you're writing C# code, whereas dimba is writing C++. C# users get all the goodies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Automatic indentation of arguments list on multiple lines in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053510/automatic-indentation-of-arguments-list-on-multiple-lines-in-visual-studio)*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there's no way "out of the box" to force Visual Studio to indent code that way. It's always going to indent wrapped function parameters with only a single tab.

It turns out that such a style is in accordance with Microsoft's general coding guidelines, and probably why they've written it that way. I don't much care for it either, though, also preferring your style.

But it turns out that you only have to manually indent the *first* wrapped parameter. Subsequently, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Visual Studio will automatically start the next line underneath your first carefully lined up parameter.

Also remember that (if you've already written the method definitions), you can select multiple lines at a time and use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to line them all up. You don't have to do one at a time.

In general, there are unfortunately *extremely* limited code formatting options available for C/C++ code in Visual Studio. The C# programmers get a lot more goodies. You might be able to invest in an add-in or extension like [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) that gets you more features in the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a duplicate of *[Automatic indentation of arguments list on multiple lines in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7053510/3681671)*. In which I provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60297501/3681671) for [Visual Studio 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2017).

Under menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Text editor* → *C/C++* → *Formatting* → *Indentation* → *"Within parentheses, align new lines when I type them"*.

Choose the option "Align contents to opening parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a tool called **Artistic Style** (short for **astyle**). It can customize almost all your required code format. Regards to your indentation format, check its document on [max‑instatement‑indent](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_max-instatement-indent).

Furthermore, this tool can be easily integrated into Visual Studio .NET (check *[this](http://www.ewanhemingway.co.uk/blog/using-astyle-visual-studio)* for a quick setup).

Comment: The first link is half-broken (the page anchor doesn't do anything) and the second link completely broken (404).

Comment: What do you expect for an answer that is 10+ years old?